# Remove single quotes from sql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to run the sql query using `codeigniter` but unable to get success due to single quotes in the query.  Following is my query:

```
function getStaffUser($uid, $participant_list=0) {

$rid='1,2,3';
$where = "FIND_IN_SET(users.role_id, '".$rid."')"; 
$where_plist = "NOT FIND_IN_SET(users.uid, '".$participant_list."')"; 

$this->db->select("users.uid, CONCAT(`users`.`given_name`, ' ',`users`.`surname`) as 'user_name'", false);
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->where("users.uid!=", $uid, false);
if($participant_list!=0){

$this->db->where($where_plist, false);    
}
$data = $this->db->get();

pr($this->db->last_query()); exit;
if ($data->num_rows() == 0)
    return false;
else
    return $data->result();
```

}

It returns the following query:

```
SELECT users.uid, CONCAT(`users`.`given_name`, ' ', `users`.`surname`) as 'user_name' FROM (`users`) WHERE FIND_IN_SET(users.role_id, '1,2,3') AND users.uid!=1 AND `NOT` FIND_IN_SET(users.uid, '1,18,60')
```

However, the query is all fine except the single quotes only on `'NOT'` in the last. If if remove that single quotes and run in the `sqlyog` it works fine.

Therefore, what is the best way to remove it. I tried to use `false` but it did not work either.

ANy help ?

Thanks.

Comment: Downvoted ? :S I can't see anything wrong with the question. I had been trying to search the solution but didn't success and eventually I put up here so I can get some help. Feedback will be appreciated if there is something wrong with the question. THanks

Comment: you need to set `$this->db->where('$where_plist', NULL, FALSE);` **instead of** `$this->db->where($where_plist, false); `

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply use `!`, like this:

```
$where_plist = "! FIND_IN_SET(users.uid, '".$participant_list."')";
```

`NOT` and `!` are aliases: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/logical-operators.html#operator_not

Comment: Still result contains the single quotes. Like this '!' which prevents sql to identify this as not operator.

Comment: Hmm, and how about doing the FIND_IN_SET thing in PHP and not even use it in the query? I know it's not a direct solution, but you should consider it. I remember in my CI days that I had many cases where I had to avoid using Active Records...

Comment: That looks like the only solution. Thanks anyway.